# yodlee: How to add site and call SOAP API

Tags: yodlee

I installed first time yconsole to check API's of yodlee.  I havent installed SSO etc.
I manage to login as a user and create a DAG simulated accoutn, however, I don't know how to add site and call API's in the yconsole ?

I see only the following options in yconsole:

---

1. Server Version
2. Register User
3. SSO Register User
4. Login User
5. SSO Login User
6. Sessionless Call [sub menu]
7. Unregister User
8. Get Oauth Access Token
9. Item Management [sub menu]
10. Manage Alerts [sub menu]
11. Manage Content Services [sub menu]
12. Transactions [sub menu]
13. Item Account Management [sub menu]
14. Quit

    ---

Choice:

When I try to view items under Item Management I get exception:

---

Choice: 1

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {http://core.soap.yodlee.com}InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFaul
t:<faultText>com.yodlee.core.SessionTimedOutException: Session timed out</faultT
ext>

InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer
.java:104)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer
.java:90)
        at com.yodlee.soap.core.InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFault.get
Deserializer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getSpecialized(B
aseDeserializerFactory.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getDeserializerA
s(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializer(Deser
ializationContext.java:464)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializerForTyp
e(DeserializationContext.java:547)
        at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.onStartChild(SOAPFaul
tDetailsBuilder.java:157)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(Deserial
izationContext.java:1035)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unkn
own Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContent
Dispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Un
known Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(Deserialization
Context.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
        at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnders
tandChecker.java:62)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at com.yodlee.soap.core.dataservice.dataservice.DataServiceSoapBindingSt
ub.getItemSummaries(Unknown Source)
        at com.yodlee.sampleapps.item.DisplayItemInfo.viewItems(DisplayItemInfo.
java:66)
        at com.yodlee.sampleapps.YodleeConsole.viewItems(YodleeConsole.java:438)

        at com.yodlee.sampleapps.YodleeConsole.itemManagementMenu(YodleeConsole.
java:165)
        at com.yodlee.sampleapps.YodleeConsole.loop(YodleeConsole.java:531)
        at com.yodlee.sampleapps.YodleeConsole.main(YodleeConsole.java:572)
********************
```

Answer (score 0):

The error stack you posted seems to indicate that your connection to the API was no longer valid because it appears you  may have been idle for 15 mins or longer. When that happens you have to log in again. Can you try again and let us know?

Regarding which item in yconsole you want #9 to add site accounts.